# Sum of calculated column

Tags: 2010

I have to display the sum of the calculated column. I have to do this in sharepoint 2010 I tried all possibilities as of my knowledge but I couldn't make it. Is there any solution for this problem, can someone help me out???

Comment: You can't do this out-of-the-box. Can you use javascript?

Comment: Can we do this using Javascript???

Comment: You can use JQuery and SPServices. But it won't adjust based on filtering. So if someone filters out half of the rows, the total won't change. Will that still work for you?

Comment: It doesn't work for me dude

Answer (score 0):

As per my understand, you want to show sum of the calculated column in list view.

Here is an [example](http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Sum) for that with code sample.

Hope this will help you.